# Attempting lens/traversal map multi-update on a subset of its keys

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

I'm trying to conjure a traversal to update multiple keys of an IntMap as a whole.

To dispell XY: I'm not simply trying to update them, I need the traversal to return to the caller for further composition.  Or at least something composable with lenses.

I've tried many variations of the common combinators.  I've tried dropping down to a functor-based definition, with a large range of experimentation shifting the `forall`s' scopes around, with no more success.  Building from the ground up again, here's where I'm at:

```
import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.Unsound

-- base case: traverse a single fixed element
t1 :: Traversal' (IntMap a) (Maybe a)
t1 = at 0

-- build-up case: traverse a pair of fixed elements
t2 :: Traversal' (IntMap a) (Maybe a)
t2 = at 0 `adjoin` at 1

-- generalizing case: do it with a fold
t3 :: Traversal' (IntMap a) (Maybe a)
t3 = foldr (\e t -> at e `adjoin` t) (at 1) [0]
```

`t1` and `t2` work fine; I'd devised `t3` to be equivalent to `t2`, but it fails with the following error:

> ```
> • Couldn't match type ‘f1’ with ‘f’
>   ‘f1’ is a rigid type variable bound by a type expected by the context:
>     Traversal' (IntMap a) (Maybe a)
>   ‘f’ is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for:
>     t3 :: forall a. Traversal' (IntMap a) (Maybe a)
>   Expected type: (Maybe a -> f1 (Maybe a)) -> IntMap a -> f1 (IntMap a)
>   Actual type: (Maybe a -> f (Maybe a)) -> IntMap a -> f (IntMap a)
> • In the second argument of ‘adjoin’, namely ‘t’   
>   In the expression: at x `adjoin` t
>   In the first argument of ‘foldr’, namely ‘(\ x t -> at x `adjoin` t)’
> ```

I suppose this is some rank-2 trickery that's still a bit over my head.  Is there any way to make this work?

I aimed for a final signature of

```
ats :: Foldable l => l Int -> Traversal' (IntMap a) (Maybe a)
```

…assuming unique keys, of course.  Which I dreamed could be implemented just almost like `t3`.

Comment: Perhaps `ifiltered` could help? http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.2/docs/Control-Lens-Combinators.html#v:ifiltered

Comment: @danidiaz: from a quick glance at it, I think not. (but could obviously be wrong) (a) I don't think I can update through a fold? and (b) the predicate-like interface makes it seem like it works by examining the keys one by one, which I can't afford, I do need the logarithmic map access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Traversal'` is a type synonym for a type containing `forall`, which makes it a second class citizen in the type system: we can't instantiate a type variable with such a type.

In particular, here we are trying to do so with `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`, we can't instantiate `b = Traversal' _ _`, because `Traversal'` contains a `forall`.

One work around is to wrap `Traversal'` in a newtype, [`ReifiedTraversal`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.2/docs/Control-Lens-Reified.html). Wrap (using the `Traversal` constructor) before passing `at 1` to `foldr`; inside `foldr`, unwrap to use `adjoin`, and rewrap; unwrap at the end.

```hs
t3 :: Traversal' (IntMap a) (Maybe a)
t3 = runTraversal (foldr (\e t -> Traversal (at e `adjoin` runTraversal t)) (Traversal (at 1)) [0])
```

---

A traversal is a function `Applicative f => (t -> f t) -> (s -> f s)`. You have a function `f :: Maybe a -> f (Maybe a)` and you want to apply it to some entries in `IntMap a`.

It's a bit of a puzzle to do with `Applicative` (there is a more natural solution using `Monad`), but requires less expertise than composing traversals as first-class values:

```hs
import Control.Applicative
import Data.IntMap (IntMap)
import qualified Data.IntMap as M

-- [Int] -> Traversal' (IntMap a) (Maybe a)
traverseAtKeys :: Applicative f => [Int] -> (Maybe a -> f (Maybe a)) -> IntMap a -> f (IntMap a)
traverseAtKeys keys f m =
  let go i k = liftA2 (insertMaybe i) (f (M.lookup i m)) k
      insertMaybe i Nothing = M.delete i
      insertMaybe i (Just v) = M.insert i v
  in foldr go (pure m) keys
```

Comment: That was perfect! With hindsight, I *have* tried a lot of things close to your direct `Applicative` implementation, but I always tried to delegate to `at` and didn't think of skipping directly to the `IntMap`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One way to get around problems like this is to use a newtype wrapper.  Specifically, consider the following:

```hs
newtype TravJoiner a b = TravJoiner { unTravJoiner :: Traversal' a b }
instance Semigroup (TravJoiner a b) where
  TravJoiner x <> TravJoiner y = TravJoiner $ adjoin x y
```

With this, you can write your `t3` without any trouble:

```hs
t3 :: Traversal' (IntMap a) (Maybe a)
t3 = unTravJoiner $ foldr (\e t -> TravJoiner (at e) <> t) (TravJoiner $ at 1) [0]
```

Your `ats` function follows nicely from there:

```hs
ats :: Foldable l => l Int -> Traversal' (IntMap a) (Maybe a)
ats = unTravJoiner . foldr (\e t -> TravJoiner (at e) <> t) (TravJoiner ignored)
```